# Character limit on body Summary field

Tags: 7, entities

I am trying to make the summary field on the body field have a limit of 40 words.
I have searched on the net so far, and I haven't found any solution.

Do you have any idea on the best approach for this?
The website is live and already has content with summaries, so I can't use a new field to do this.
am working with drupal 7

Comment: Drupal 6 or 7? Is it important the the limit is measured in words and not characters? Otherwise, take a look at the [Maxlength module](http://drupal.org/project/maxlength)

Comment: the Maxlength module does work with the character field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after little bit of more research i was able to solve this i used the [hook_form form_id()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) and some custom javascript in a custom module to do this and it works great for me am open to suggestion on how to improve the code. here is how my module looks like.
in the module file i have this function

```
     function summary_limiter_form_blog_node_form_alter(&$form, $form_id)
{
 drupal_add_js(array('summary_limiter' => array('blog_node_form' => TRUE)), 'setting');
}
```

My Java script file looks like this

```
var maxwords = 40; 
var max_words_val;
(function ($) {   
    Drupal.behaviors.summary_limiter = 
    {
         init: function()
         {
                          var summary_field =$('.text-summary');
                          $('.description').append(" <b id='summary_limiter_rem_counts'>"+maxwords +"</b> word(s) remaining")

           summary_field.keyup(function() 
           {summary_limiter.check_length(summary_field, $('#summary_limiter_rem_counts'))});


        },
       check_length: function(obj, rem,cnt)
          {
               var ary = obj.val().split(" ");  
                var len = ary.length;
                rem.html(maxwords - len);  
                if (len > maxwords) 
                { 
                rem.html(0);
                obj.val(max_words_val);
                }  
                max_words_val =obj.val();

          },
        attach: function (context, settings) {
            try{
               if(settings.summary_limiter.blog_node_form){
                    this.init();
                }
            } catch(ex){}
        }
    };


})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 3):

The answers on [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/59046/modifying-drupal-core-search-module-image-module/59051#59051) might help you.

You override maxlength in a [`hook_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7).

```
function hook_form_[content-type]_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['summary']['#maxlength'] = 40;
}
```

The above is not tested but should get you started. You can inspect the `$form` object with `dpm()` if you have Devel installed to check the exact name and place in the `$form` array of the summary field.

Comment: This question is about limiting the summary to 40 words; the other question is about the title assigned to images.

Comment: That's true. Is a `hook_form_alter()` not the best way to do this, though? I'm confused about the removal of the tag, since I don't know of another method of changing field character lengths post-creation.

Comment: [tag:hook-form-alter] should be added when the question is about `hook_form_alter()`, not when an answer suggest to use it. The answer should be tailored for the question, not link to a different question where the solution is using `hook_form_alter()` for a different form, and with a different purpose.

Answer (score 0):

There's some work going on in the [Maxlength](https://drupal.org/project/maxlength) project to implement this: https://drupal.org/node/1496570. It might be worth checking out/contributing to.